# What does this return statement do inside a service

Tags: angularjs

Im going through one of the Pluralsight courses on AngularJS with MVC5 and one of the services has this as a return statement and it looks rather strange.  Im not sure what this is doing

```
return {
    insertEmployee: insertEmployee,
    updateEmployee: updateEmployee,
    getEmployee:getEmployee

};
```

the insert/update/get names are names of methods in the service, but I dont understand the return statement.  What is this doing?

Comment: Is it a factory or a service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns an object with those methods available, example:

```
var methods = {
    insertEmployee: insertEmployee,
    updateEmployee: updateEmployee,
    getEmployee:getEmployee
}
```

Now you can do:

```
methods.insertEmployee(); //etc...
```

Comment: Ok, that seems reasonable.  Its just that ive not seen that syntax, including the example you give.  I was not aware you could define a object like that in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Actually calling a service/factory (Both can be used the same way actually, despite the fact they're not intended to work the same way.) is just calling a function. The function you defined.

If you do this :

Service :

```
var myfunction = function(){
 alert("hello");
}
```

Without any return you will not see this function in your controller.

Controller :

```
 myservice.myfunction(); will not work.
```

You need to return an object to be able to use the functions.

Service :

```
var myfunction = function(){
 alert("hello");
}

return {
  myfunction: myfunction;
}
```

This will allow you to use the service this way in your controller :

```
myservice.myfunction();
```

I usually prefer to use the object syntax in an other way, but this is just a matter of tastes :

Service :

```
var service = {};

service.myfunction = function(){
   alert("hello");
}

return service;
```

This will also allow you to use this syntax in the controller :

```
myservice.myfunction();
```

Hope it helped, if you have anymore question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can understand it as [`AngularJS defines a factory like that`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). It just means: I want to expose the functions `insertEmployee`, `updateEmployee`, and `getEmployee` to the users of this `factory`.

Please refer to [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory).

In this way, say, your factory name is `myFactory`, the usage is like:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
     .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function ($scope, myFactory) {
          myFactory.getEmployee();
  }]);
```